# Where do I find CRS axis names?

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, naming-conventions

When using the `SUBSETTINGCRS` argument of a WCS query, one needs to provide the axis labels in the subsetting CRS.

[This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/284749/159691) to [GeoServer does not work WCS parameters "subsettingcrs" and "outputcrs"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284720/geoserver-does-not-work-wcs-parameters-subsettingcrs-and-outputcrs) states that

> The axis names can be checked from http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/3857 and they appear to be
>
> > Cartesian 2D CS. Axes: easting, northing (X,Y). Orientations: east, north. UoM: m.

However I don’t see this mention or any mention related to axis on the provided link, for this particular CRS or others.

How do I check what are the axis names for a particular CRS ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the format of the XML report has been changed and it is now more complicated for beginners.

If you just want to see the axis order with your eyes it is easiest to make a text search with "3857" at https://epsg.org. The result is one hit that leads to

https://epsg.org/crs_3857/WGS-84-Pseudo-Mercator.html?

The Coordinate System Details section gives the desired information:

```
Cartesian 2D CS. Axes: easting, northing (X,Y). Orientations: east, north. UoM: m.
```

When using the original link or the URL of the new REST API of epsg.org user must know how the system is working.

1. EPSG:3857 is a Projected Coordinate System

```
      <gml:ProjectedCRS xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
      xmlns:epsg="urn:x-ogp:spec:schema-xsd:EPSG:2.2:dataset" 
      xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" gml:id="epsg-crs-3857">
```

2. From the bottom of the document you can find that 3857 is based on a Cartesian Coordinate System with EPSG code 4449

```
<gml:cartesianCS xlink:href="https://apps.epsg.org/api/v1/CoordSystem/4499/export?format=gml"/>
```

3. The provided link https://apps.epsg.org/api/v1/CoordSystem/4499/export?format=gml gives details of this Cartesian system, includina axis names, axis abbreviations, and axis order.

```
<gml:CartesianCS xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:epsg="urn:x-ogp:spec:schema-xsd:EPSG:2.2:dataset" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" gml:id="epsg-cs-4499">
<gml:metaDataProperty>
<epsg:CommonMetaData>
<epsg:type>cartesian</epsg:type>
<epsg:informationSource>OGP</epsg:informationSource>
<epsg:revisionDate>2001-04-29</epsg:revisionDate>
<epsg:changes/>
<epsg:isDeprecated>false</epsg:isDeprecated>
</epsg:CommonMetaData>
</gml:metaDataProperty>
<gml:identifier codeSpace="EPSG">4499</gml:identifier>
<gml:name>Cartesian 2D CS. Axes: easting, northing (X,Y). Orientations: east, north. UoM: m.</gml:name>
<gml:remarks>Used in projected and engineering coordinate reference systems.</gml:remarks>
<gml:axis>
<gml:CoordinateSystemAxis gml:id="epsg-axis-41" uom="9001">
<gml:descriptionReference xlink:href="https://apps.epsg.org/api/v1/CoordinateAxisName/9906/export?format=gml"/>
<gml:identifier codeSpace="EPSG">41</gml:identifier>
<gml:axisAbbrev>X</gml:axisAbbrev>
<gml:axisDirection codeSpace="EPSG">east</gml:axisDirection>
</gml:CoordinateSystemAxis>
</gml:axis>
<gml:axis>
<gml:CoordinateSystemAxis gml:id="epsg-axis-42" uom="9001">
<gml:descriptionReference xlink:href="https://apps.epsg.org/api/v1/CoordinateAxisName/9907/export?format=gml"/>
<gml:identifier codeSpace="EPSG">42</gml:identifier>
<gml:axisAbbrev>Y</gml:axisAbbrev>
<gml:axisDirection codeSpace="EPSG">north</gml:axisDirection>
</gml:CoordinateSystemAxis>
</gml:axis>
</gml:CartesianCS>
```

It is also possible to see the axis names with one request into the EPSG API https://apps.epsg.org/api/swagger/ui/index by using WKT as outputformat.

https://apps.epsg.org/api/v1/CoordRefSystem/3857/export/?format=WKT

The response contains these strings

```
...AXIS["Easting (X)",east,ORDER[1]],AXIS["Northing (Y)",north,ORDER[2]]...
```

If you have Proj and its utility programs available on your computer you can also use projinfo for finding the axis info. It should be exactly same WKT than the one from the EPSG service but more conveniently formatted. GDAL utility gdalsrsinfo is also doing about the same thing.

```
projinfo epsg:3857 -o WKT2:2019
WKT2:2019 string:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator",
        METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",1024]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting (X)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["northing (Y)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World - 85┬░S to 85┬░N"],
        BBOX[-85.06,-180,85.06,180]],
    ID["EPSG",3857]]
```

Comment: Thanks, it’s not straightforward indeed, and each method seems to have its drawbacks : for the first one the axis abbreviations are embedded in a JavaScript folded table (for 3857 it’s in the title, but not e.g. for 4326), several steps are needed for the second one, and for the third one the label is merged with the name…

Comment: Anyway, it is surprising how everywhere the horizontal axis for EPSG 4326 is advertised as "**Lon**" when WCS requests only seem to accept "**Long**" (at least for GeoServer, but also apparently for MapServer).

Comment: It has changed not too long ago. I feel too lazy for finding the exact date. I will add one more method (projinfo) into my question.

Comment: I just had to find the reference because this is so odd detail. In http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-146r6/09-146r6.html `The following envelope, encoded in XML, utilizes EPSG 4326 with two axis labels, “Lat” and “Long.” These labels correspond to the CRS axis abbreviations of EPSG v8.5, but not to EPSG v8.9.2 where the axis abbreviation for Longitude has been changed to “Lon”. `

Comment: For future searchers: WCSs can use arbitrary names for their axes so you might get "Lon", "Long", "Longdongjohnron" or "baNaNA" or whatever they want. It is right in the next example in the linked PDF.