# Identifying axes for WCS subset requests

Tags: coordinate-system, ogc, wcs

https://ows.rasdaman.org/rasdaman/ows?&SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=2.1.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities provides various WCS coverages, for example https://ows.rasdaman.org/rasdaman/ows?&SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=2.1.0&REQUEST=DescribeCoverage&COVERAGEID=AverageChloroColor:

```
<gml:Envelope srsName="http://crs.rasdaman.com/def/crs-compound?1=http://crs.rasdaman.com/def/crs/OGC/0/AnsiDate&2=http://crs.rasdaman.com/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326" axisLabels="ansi Lat Lon" uomLabels="d degree degree" srsDimension="3">
  <gml:lowerCorner>"2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" -90 -180</gml:lowerCorner>
  <gml:upperCorner>"2015-05-01T00:00:00.000Z" 90 180</gml:upperCorner>
</gml:Envelope>
```

https://maps.dwd.de/geoserver/dwd/ows?service=WCS&version=2.1.0&request=GetCapabilities also has some WCS Coverages, for example https://maps.dwd.de/geoserver/dwd/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=DescribeCoverage&COVERAGEID=dwd__Natural_Earth_Map:

```
<gml:Envelope srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326" axisLabels="Lat Long" uomLabels="Deg Deg" srsDimension="2">
  <gml:lowerCorner>-90.000000000036 -180.0</gml:lowerCorner>
  <gml:upperCorner>90.00000000000001 180.00000000007202</gml:upperCorner>
</gml:Envelope>
```

Or https://maps.dwd.de/geoserver/dwd/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=DescribeCoverage&COVERAGEID=dwd__ORKA-DE_UZVZ:

```
<gml:EnvelopeWithTimePeriod srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/25832" axisLabels="E N time" uomLabels="m m s" srsDimension="2">
  <gml:lowerCorner>333340.0 5259975.0</gml:lowerCorner>
  <gml:upperCorner>839975.0 5673129.0</gml:upperCorner>
  <gml:beginPosition>2021-09-28T12:00:00.000Z</gml:beginPosition>
  <gml:endPosition>2021-09-28T12:50:00.000Z</gml:endPosition>
</gml:EnvelopeWithTimePeriod>
```

When I make a `GetCoverage` request for a subset I have to provide the subsetting CRS as well as ranges in the axes and their names, e. g. for the Rasdaman `AverageChloroColor` demo something like:

```
&SUBSETTINGCRS=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fdef%2Fcrs%2FEPSG%2F0%2F4326
&SUBSET=Lat%2850%2C51%29
&SUBSET=Lon%289%2C10%29
```

or for the `dwd__Natural_Earth_Map` something like ("Long" instead of "Lon" here):

```
&SUBSETTINGCRS=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fdef%2Fcrs%2FEPSG%2F0%2F4326
&SUBSET=Lat%2850%2C51%29
&SUBSET=Long%289%2C10%29
```

or for the `dwd__ORKA-DE_UZVZ` something like this (untested!):

```
&SUBSETTINGCRS=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fdef%2Fcrs%2FEPSG%2F0%2F25832
&SUBSET=E%28500000%2C550000%29
&SUBSET=N%285500000%2C5600000%29
```

Now I might have extents in other CRS which I need to transform for the WCS subset requests.

For example an extent in EPSG:25832 (UTM 32N) such as 490000 5590000 510000 5600000
which I can transform to EPSG:4326 50.5 9 50.6 9.2 (roughly).

How can I find the correct match between the axes of my extent system and the one of the WCS? I.e. how do I know programmatically which values I would put into which labeled subset?

As a concrete example: If I know that 50.5 and 50.6 are my latitudes and 9 and 9.2 are my longitudes, how do I know programatically that (for the `AverageChloroColor` example) it's `Lat(50.5, 50.6)` and `Lon(9, 9.2)` and not `Lat(9, 9.2)` and `Lon(50.5, 50.6)`?

Comment: I suspect that the `<gml:sequenceRule axisOrder="...">` might be of help but I was not able to find the meaning of the "+1" or "+2" values in the jungle of ungoogleble cascading OGC standards.

Comment: WCS 2.0 is a forgiving standard. The axis labels matter but the order not, so `&SUBSET=Lat...&SUBSET=Long...` is as correct as  `&SUBSET=Long...&SUBSET=Lat...`

Comment: Its the axis names that I cannot match though, not their order in the request.

Comment: As you noticed, the axis names for the default CRS can be captured from the DescribeCoverage. For other CRSs you must check the abbreviations from the register, for example https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/25832 shows that the axis are E,N. About Lon vs Long, see the last comment in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377221/where-do-i-find-crs-axis-names.

Comment: The sequence rule means that if the CRS has `axisLabels="ansi Lat Lon"`, and the rule is `axisOrder="+2 +3 +1"`, then in the returned data the coordinates appear in order Lat,Lon,ansi.

Comment: Hm, maybe my question is not clear enough? I know how to find the names but I do not know how to find out how to know which number in a http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/XXXX related coordinate tuple like "12.3 45.6" corresponds to which axis. Maybe it is not really a WCS question, I am not sure.

Comment: You must check a) the axis order of the CRS from the EPSG site and then b) the axis order sequence used in the data. For example with a GeoServer demo layer http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=DescribeCoverage&coverageID=nurc__Img_Sample. CRS is `"http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326" axisLabels="Lat Long"`and `sequenceRule axisOrder="+2 +1"`. So, in the GeoTIFF response the pixels appear in Long-Lat order.

Comment: In WCS 2.0 (and latest versions of WMS/WFS) the axis order must follow the axis order declared by the CRS authority (usually EPSG)

Comment: Is it clear now or are you still confused?

Comment: Still not clear to me how I get to a solution with just the WCS service's responses and the linked XMLs. I will update the question tomorrow I think. It should probably read more like "how to find the axis names/definitions and order" because the former is still a mystery to me. I see no way yet to know if "Lon", "Long" or "WhateverAnotherServiceCallsItsAxes" is a latitude, longitude, a x or y axis or whatever.

Comment: Title updated!
The labels are arbitrary names set by the service. If I have `axisLabels="Lat Long"` and `sequenceRule axisOrder="+2 +1"`, how do I know which one is the x and which one is the y?

Comment: Hm, it would make sense if `axisLabels` means "these are the labels to use for the axes of the CRS" and the `axisOrder` said which label references which axis. But then where can I find out which/how many axes the CRS has? At least https://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326 does not directly tell me.

Comment: Actually, `axisOrder` seems to be unrelated to the correspondence between the axes of the CRS and the `axisLabels`. I think I chased a red herring.