# Axes labels/names of QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gdal, proj

Consider the following CRS as examples:

```
QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(4326)
QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(25832)
QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(3857)
QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(3035)
```

How can I get the short names or labels of the axes programmatically? For example, according to [https://apps.epsg.org/api/v1/CoordRefSystem/[ID]/export/?format=WKT](https://apps.epsg.org/api/v1/CoordRefSystem/%5BID%5D/export/?format=WKT):

- 4326: Lat, Lon
- 25832: E, N
- 3857: X, Y
- 3035: Y, X

[Where do I find CRS axis names?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377221/where-do-i-find-crs-axis-names) shows how complicated it is to traverse through multiple layers of OGC standardization and I wonder if QGIS (or `proj`?) might have a straightforward way. After all, if you have QGIS or `proj` installed, you have the same data local, right?

A solution that uses something from QGIS OR something that is a dependency of QGIS (i.e. installed, like `proj` or `gdal`) is ok.

---

Not a solution:
QGIS theoretically offers some functionality around this since 3.26 but sadly it only displays the north or east component, not the actual abbreviation strings:

QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem provides a method .axisOrdering() which returns the axes of the CRS as [Qgis.CrsAxisDirection](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/Qgis.html#qgis.core.Qgis.CrsAxisDirection) objects. These objects can be passed to [QgsCoordinateReferenceSystemUtils.axisDirectionToAbbreviatedString()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsCoordinateReferenceSystemUtils.html#qgis.core.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystemUtils.axisDirectionToAbbreviatedString) (also available since 3.26) to get an abbreviated string. But as I said, those are only N or E:

```
for epsg_code in [3035, 3857, 4326, 25832]:
  crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.fromEpsgId(epsg_code)
  print(crs)
  for axis_direction in crs.axisOrdering():
    abbrev = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystemUtils.axisDirectionToAbbreviatedString(axis_direction)
    print(f"{axis_direction} -> {abbrev}")
```

results in:

```
<QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem: EPSG:3035>
0 -> N
4 -> E
<QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem: EPSG:3857>
4 -> E
0 -> N
<QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem: EPSG:4326>
0 -> N
4 -> E
<QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem: EPSG:25832>
4 -> E
0 -> N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution that I like even more was [suggested by @user30184 in another question's comment section](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/461300/availability-of-www-opengis-net-crs-database?noredirect=1#comment753503_461300): `projinfo`

`projinfo` is available when QGIS is available and it supports OGC URIs. Also it is able to output nicely parseable JSON in the [PROJJSON](https://proj.org/en/latest/specifications/projjson.html) format since PROJ 6.2.

```
# tested on Linux and Windows, not on MacOS
# Note: Shell output encoding might not be "utf-8" everywhere?
epsg_code = "31467"
ogc_uri_base = "http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/{epsg_code}"
crs_ogc_uri = ogc_uri_base.format(epsg_code=epsg_code)
projinfo_invocation = f"projinfo -q -o PROJJSON {crs_ogc_uri}"
projinfo_output = subprocess.run(projinfo_invocation, capture_output=True, shell=True)
projjson = None
if projinfo_output.stdout:
  projjson = json.loads(projinfo_output.stdout.decode("utf-8"))
else:
  raise Exception(projinfo_output.stderr)
print(projjson["coordinate_system"]["axis"])
```

results in

```
[{'name': 'Northing',
  'abbreviation': 'X',
  'direction': 'north',
  'unit': 'metre'},
 {'name': 'Easting',
  'abbreviation': 'Y',
  'direction': 'east',
  'unit': 'metre'}]
```

Or for 25832:

```
[{'name': 'Easting',
  'abbreviation': 'E',
  'direction': 'east',
  'unit': 'metre'},
 {'name': 'Northing',
  'abbreviation': 'N',
  'direction': 'north',
  'unit': 'metre'}]
```

and 4326:

```
[{'name': 'Geodetic latitude',
  'abbreviation': 'Lat',
  'direction': 'north',
  'unit': 'degree'},
 {'name': 'Geodetic longitude',
  'abbreviation': 'Lon',
  'direction': 'east',
  'unit': 'degree'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Proj comes with a SQLite database named "proj.db". The axis names, abbreviations, and axis order can be queried with SQL from this database by joining table "axis" to either "projected_crs" or "geodetic_crs".

An example query for EPSG:31467 https://epsg.io/31467.wkt2

```
select p.code,a.coordinate_system_order,a.name,a.abbrev
from axis a
join projected_crs p on a.coordinate_system_code=p.coordinate_system_code
where p.code=31467
order by a.coordinate_system_order

code    coordinate_system_order name    abbrev
31467   1                       Northing    X
31467   2                       Easting     Y
```

Another example querying both projected and geodetic CRS' to find EPSG:4326:

```
select coalesce(p.code, g.code), a.coordinate_system_order, a.name,a.abbrev             
from axis a
join projected_crs p on a.coordinate_system_code=p.coordinate_system_code
join geodetic_crs g on a.coordinate_system_code=g.coordinate_system_code
where p.code=4326 or g.code=4326
order by a.coordinate_system_order

code    coordinate_system_order name              abbrev
4326    1                       Geodetic latitude   Lat
4326    2                       Geodetic longitude  Lon
```